# access IMDB watchlist in CSV format

Tags: python, https

IMDB allows you to create a watchlist, which can be easily exported in CSV format. I would like to be able to do this programmatically using Python.

The problem I am facing is that I can obviously not access it without logging in. If I try to access it directly I get the 404 response. So I figure, I will need to log in first, and attempt to get fetch the data afterwards.

Looking at the HTML code, I find that at least one of the login forms has these inputs:

```
<input type="hidden" name="49e6c" value="898d" />
<input id="usernameprompt" type="text" size="20" name="login" value="" >
<input id="passwordprompt" type="password" size="20" name="password">
<input type="submit" class="linkasbutton-primary" value="Login!">
```

The values in the first input have not changed yet, so I figure that is not yet an issue.

The location of the form is at https://secure.imdb.com/register-imdb/login?ref_=nv_usr_lgin_3, designated IMDBLOGIN in the code.

Now I would like to use this information to log in, using the name of each input as key and value as value:

```
form = OrderedDict([("49e6c", "898d"), ("login", username), ("password",  password), ("submit", "submit")])
url = urlsplit(IMDBLOGIN)
try:
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(url.netloc)
    request = url.path + "?" + url.query + "&" + urlencode(form)
    conn.putrequest("POST", request)
    conn.putheader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    conn.endheaders()
    loggedin = conn.getresponse()
    logger.debug("Log in first %s %s %s", loggedin.status, loggedin.reason, loggedin.getheaders())
except:
    logger.exception("Can't log in via HTTPS")
finally:
    conn.close()
```

The problem is that I am unsure what to do with the submit input. The result I am now getting is 400 (Bad request).

Furthermore I don't know if I am on the right track anyway. Any considerations are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it is not actually that difficult. To make things easier I have switched from httplib to urllib2.

```
IMDBLOGIN = "https://secure.imdb.com/register/login?ref_=nv_usr_lgin_3"
form = OrderedDict([("49e6c", "3478"), ("login", self.username), ("password",  self.password)])
cj = CookieJar()
opener = build_opener(HTTPHandler(), HTTPSHandler(), HTTPErrorProcessor(), 
                     HTTPRedirectHandler(), HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
params = urlencode(form)
response = opener.open(IMDBLOGIN, params)

# cookies automatically sent
response2 = opener.open(csv_url)
content = response2.read()
```

Basically, I do not need to add the submit input, and so far I have not been able to figure out what purpose the first input has, because I seem to be able to fill in any value. (Though not extensively tested)

After logging in I make sure that I keep the cookie for the next request, and retrieve the file.

Comment: Hi, I've been trying to make this work with regular IMDB and it doesn't seem to work at all. Here's the code http://dpaste.com/hold/1594124/ (identical to yours basically) and the response I'm getting is a 400: Bad Request. Any ideas on why this wouldn't work?

Comment: @reese, I am assuming you use the same url? Try logging out. Go to https://secure.imdb.com/register-imdb/login?ref_=nv_usr_lgin_3# and look at the source of that page. Look for the imdb-login div. The first input of the form in there has type hidden and for me the name attribute is 49e6c, but perhaps it is different for you. Let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to use a inspector, like Chrome's "F12" developer tools, to take a look at the request that IMDB sends to itself in response to the user filling out the login form. When I did this, I noticed similar form values to the ones you had, though there are also cookies and other information that IMDB may be relying on to allow the authentication to complete. This is, of course, a notoriously fragile type of code.

If this is just for your own personal use, you could also consider simply signing in to IMDB from your browser, then finding the cookies that are set in your browser session and use them in your requests. This is the technique used by [IMDbPY](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/), which you might consider looking at.

Comment: In order to find the actual forms values I had to disable javascript in Firefox, otherwise the page would be reloaded after sending the post request. I do need the cookie returned after logging in, but that's it..:)